# create a Grok filter for a specific date pattern in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to use ELK stack to store old logs.
** This is not a duplicate question. Please read below for details. **
I want to parse timestamp from my message which looks like below:

> Apr 1 04:01:04 i-b73lj53l journal: 152.17.62.1 - - [31/Mar/2017:20:01:04 +0000] "GET /api/people/5913b19b31b0f601004875a5?access_token=rNL7S4A2o5BdbX1QDxbL9L5Vx7j60kGIIhQ1tk9yDYRjUf5e8OKzGGnIDTrMXr5n&filter=%7B%22order%22%3A%22createdAt%20DESC%22%2C%22include%22%3A%5B%7B%22relation%22%3A%22friendships%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%22trashedAt%22%3A%7B%22exists%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22include%22%3A%5B%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 346 "http://api.mywebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.104 Safari/537.36 Core/1.53.4549.400 Mozilla/9.7.12900.400"

I have tried already for more than **20 hours** and it seems my configuration is not being read at all because even if I add **add_field** or **remove_field**, there is no change in data.

> I have already enabled system logs as per the documentation filebeat documentation.

My std output looks like this:

```
   DEBUG    [publish]   pipeline/processor.go:275   Publish event: 


{
  "@timestamp": "2018-04-05T18:53:08.817Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "doc",
    "version": "6.2.3"
  },
  "source": "/Users/garry/project/sampel",
  "offset": 3231104,
  "tags": [
    "message-log"
  ],
  "prospector": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "fields": {
    "env": "dev"
  },
  "beat": {
    "name": "Garry-MacBook-Pro-2.local",
    "hostname": "Garry-MacBook-Pro-2.local",
    "version": "6.2.3"
  },
  "message": "Apr 1 04:01:04 i-b73lj53l journal: 152.17.62.1 - - [31/Mar/2017:20:01:04 +0000] "GET /api/people/5913b19b31b0f601004875a5?access_token=rNL7S4A2o5BdbX1QDxbL9L5Vx7j60kGIIhQ1tk9yDYRjUf5e8OKzGGnIDTrMXr5n&filter=%7B%22order%22%3A%22createdAt%20DESC%22%2C%22include%22%3A%5B%7B%22relation%22%3A%22friendships%22%2C%22scope%22%3A%7B%22where%22%3A%7B%22trashedAt%22%3A%7B%22exists%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22include%22%3A%5B%22 HTTP/1.1" 200 346 "http://api.mywebsite.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.104 Safari/537.36 Core/1.53.4549.400 Mozilla/9.7.12900.400"\"
}
```

My current config is:

```
filter {
  grok {
   match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:syslog_timestamp} %{SYSLOGHOST:syslog_hostname} %{DATA:syslog_program}(?:\[%{POSINT:syslog_pid}\])?: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z",  "d/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your grok filter is doing, but your log is a `syslog` so you can simply create a filter using `%{SYSLOGLINE}`

you can then parse, `[31/Mar/2017:20:01:04 +0000]` which is stored in a message `field` as follows,

```
\[%{MONTHDAY:monthday}/%{MONTH:month}/%{YEAR:year}:%{TIME:time}.%{ISO8601_TIMEZONE:Timezone}\]
```

which will produce following output,

```
{
  "monthday": [
    "31"
  ],
  "month": [
    "Mar"
  ],
  "year": [
    "2017"
  ],
  "time": [
    "20:01:04"
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    "20",
    "00"
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    "01",
    "00"
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    "04"
  ],
  "Timezone": [
    "+0000"
  ]
}
```